# How to cut repeating string in animation in python

Tags: python-3.x, loading, pleasewait

I have developed a script for some operations on docx files. That script takes 5 to 20 seconds to execute the output because of the huge process inside the docx. So on that time the user will get confuse wheter the script is running or not. For that I decided to put an animation and I am done with it. The problem is repetition.

It looks like

[image]

I don't want to print the "Please Wait..." as a repeated one. My need here is that "please wait..." should print once until the progress done after that the "process wait..." should disappear. I'm using python 3.

Here my Code:

```
import glob
from docx import Document
import sys
import time
import threading

class Spinner:
    busy = False
    delay = 0.1

    @staticmethod
    def spinning_cursor():
        while 1: 
            for cursor in 'Please Wait...': yield cursor

    def __init__(self, delay=None):
        self.spinner_generator = self.spinning_cursor()
        if delay and float(delay): self.delay = delay

    def spinner_task(self):
        while self.busy:
            sys.stdout.write(next(self.spinner_generator))
            time.sleep(self.delay)
    def start(self):
        self.busy = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.spinner_task).start()

    def stop(self):
        self.busy = False
        time.sleep(self.delay)
i = 0
j=0


spinner = Spinner()
spinner.start()

for name in glob.glob('Test_Plan/*.docx'):
 doc=Document(name)
 for t in doc.tables:
    for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="ID" :
            i=i+1
print("Total Number of Tables: ", i)
spinner.stop()

for name in glob.glob('Test_Plan/*.docx'):
    doc=Document(name)
    for table in doc.tables:
     for ro in table.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Automated Test Case" and (ro.cells[2].text=="yes" or ro.cells[2].text=="Yes"):
            j=j+1
print("Total Number of YES Automations: ", j)

k = 0
for name in glob.glob('Test_Plan/*.docx'):
    doc=Document(name)
    for t in doc.tables:
     for ro in t.rows:
        if ro.cells[0].text=="Automated Test Case" and (ro.cells[2].text=="no" or ro.cells[2].text=="No"):
            k=k+1
print("Total Number of NO Automations: ", k)
```

Comment: Showing us your code would maybe help us to help you solving the issue.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: If you want to print one time, why don't you use `print('Please Wait...)` once at the beginning?

Comment: Can you explain @Alperen